# How do I make a Python unit test that fails when an exception is handled?

Tags: python, unit-testing, except

I am trying to make a Python unit test that will pass if no exceptions are raised and fail if any are (even if they are handled).

My code is basically like this:

```
def do_something():
    try:
        # Do some code
        pass
    except:
        print("An exception was raised")

class TestDoSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_do_something(self):
        do_something()
```

But this test will pass regardless of any exceptions raised in the `try` block.

How do I get this test to fail if an exception is raised?

I have already tried the various answers along the lines of

```
def test_do_something(self):
    try:
        do_something()
    except:
        self.fail("An exception was raised")
```

These answers result in the exception being swallowed by the code being tested.

Comment: A test should only fail if code doesn't do what it was supposed to do. If your code isn't supposed to handle an exception, don't catch it (or at least re-raise it).

Comment: This is a bad idea. Exception handling is part of normal control flow in Python - `for` loops and `await` both end by catching an exception that signals that they're done. A test that fails if any exceptions were handled fails if the tested code ran a `for` loop.

Comment: You could perhaps break `do_something` into more atomic units of code. A tight unit that simply "does something", and leaves exception handling to its caller, is better fitted to the kind of unit testing you want.

Comment: (It's also a bad idea because it's trying to test the internal logic of the tested code, rather than the observable behavior.)

Comment: I need the exception handling to send an email to myself with traceback if someone runs my code and provides some bad input.  How would you recommend getting the traceback in that case?

Comment: Split the current `do_something` into two functions. One function contains the logic and allows exceptions to propagate; the second function calls the first and does what's necessary with any exceptions raised. Then both are unit testable. You can test that the first function raises exceptions when it should; and you can test the behaviour of the calling function in exception scenarios (for example, test the second function's exception-handlling behaviour by mock.patching the first function with something that always throws).

Comment: Stepping back a bit - what this is demonstrating is that writing unit tests often stimulates you to sharpen your definition of what your code units are, and promotes more atomic design.

Comment: Your test needs to 1) set up the necessary condition for the exception to be raised. Once it does that, it calls the function, then 2) checks to see if the e-mail was sent. If the e-mail is not, then the test should fail.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is one example, why a bare except statement is a problematic solution.

If you decide to go this path anyway, you could probably mock the print function to return the string and test, if this return value is your print string.